# CSS, SVG: line/path-markers do not work as expected

Tags: css, html, svg

If I have more than one SVG with a marker inside then only the marker of the 1st SVG is shown. I would expect to see the marker in both SVGs.

That is only the case if I have CSS in place to habe it like a tooltip (appear only if hover over).

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>
.tt svg
{
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
 border: 1px black solid;
}

.tt:hover svg
{
 display: inline;
}
</style>

<p class="tt">aaa
 <svg width="100px" height="100px" style="border: 1px solid red;">
 <marker id='head' orient="auto" markerWidth="2" markerHeight="4"      
  refX="0.1" refY="2">
 <path d='M0,0 V4 L2,2 Z' fill="grey"/></marker>
 <line x1="20" y1="40" x2="70" y2="40" stroke="grey" stroke-width="3px"  
  marker-end="url(#head)"/>     
</svg>


<p class="tt">bbb
 <svg width="100px" height="100px" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <marker id='head' orient="auto" markerWidth="2" markerHeight="4"  
   refX="0.1" refY="2">
  <path d='M0,0 V4 L2,2 Z' fill="grey"/></marker>
  <line x1="20" y1="40" x2="70" y2="40" stroke="grey" stroke-width="3px" 
   marker-end="url(#head)"/>     
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Both SVGs are the same.

You can see when hovering over "bbb" there are no markers in the 2nd SVG.

I tried with multiple browsers and it is always the same effect - so I think it is an error with my markup.

It is working if I remove the CSS (e.g. rename tt to ttt in the CSS) but then I do not have the tooltip effect.

And it is also working if I use a different marker-id (e.g. head1) in one of the SVGs.

Why is that?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same id on the same page, even if they are in different svgs. Maybe try this, assuming the browser issue has been resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233279/externally-defined-markers-dont-appear-in-svg

Comment: That sounds feasible (duplicated IDs) - but why is it working without the CSS then?

Comment: Display none disables CSS. Fill is A CSS property.

Comment: I tried display, visibility and opacity. It only works with the last (opacity). Why does the reset of display or visibility to show again not affect the SVGs marker?