# How to move svg path out of html

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using this example from [Chris Coyer](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lcDBd)

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    mlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display: none;">

<defs>
<g id="icon-image">
<path class="path1" d="M0 4v26h32v-26h-32zM30 28h-28v-22h28v22zM22 11c0-1.657 1.343-3 3-3s3 1.343 3 3c0 1.657-1.343 3-3 3-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3zM28 26h-24l6-16 8 10 4-3z"></path>
</g>
</defs>
</svg>

<h1>
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-phone"></use>
 </svg>
Call me
```

However, I would like the path definitions to NOT be in the html as they will be used throughout the app.

Is this possible? (Note: I have read the answer that suggests javascript to manually inject the svg into the html.  I don't want to do that either.)

I know there are many ways of embedding/linking SVG paths and files.  And I have tried them all.  In particular, I need to be able to style it to the currentColor. As covered in detail in this [blog post](https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/), this cannot be done with external SVG files which are then used in an img tag.

So the closest thing I have found is this example above.  However, I still don't want the path embedded in the html.  If I could somehow get it in an external file of some type so it is reusable, that would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215009/how-to-reference-external-svg-file-in-svg-correctly

Comment: I read that question, but I don't see an answer that applies here.

Comment: Why not convert your SVG icons into a font?

Comment: Another option is making a SVG sprite and load it with your CSS using data uri

Comment: @LGSon How do you convert to a font?  That sounds like a great idea!

Comment: Search the internet for "convert SVG to font" and you get a bunch of sites/tools doing that

Comment: Excellent.  If you want to post that as an answer, I will accept.  I did not know that could be one.  Suddenly, I understand what font-awesome is all about.

Comment: Thanks ... posted an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to convert SVG to a font

Searching the internet for "convert SVG to font" will give you a lot of sites/tools doing that, like:

- https://icomoon.io/app/#/select
- https://glyphter.com/
- http://fontastic.me/

Also "HTML entities" have some reusable icons etc.

- https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 0):

There's only one remaining option here. You don't want to embed the svg manually, you don't want to inject it with javascript and you don't want to use it in an img tag since you want to modify the properties with css. The only remaining solution would be to use your server-side language to inject it.

If you're using php, you can simply echo the content of your svg file where you want:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(file_path); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option I found is SVG Sprites, explained in detail by [Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>
  .icon {
width: 125px;
height: 125px;
background: #eee;
      fill: currentColor;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="color: red">
    <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="menu.svg#beaker"/></svg>
</div>
<div style="color: brown">
    <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="menu.svg#fish" /></svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then this in a separate file called menu.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'>
```

```
<symbol id="fish" viewBox="0 26 100 48">
    <path d="M98.5,47.5C96.5,45.5,81,35,62,35c-2.1,0-4.2,0.1-6.2,0.3L39,26c0,4.5,1.3,9,2.4,12.1C31.7,40.7,23.3,44,16,44L0,34
c0,8,4,16,4,16s-4,8-4,16l16-10c7.3,0,15.7,3.3,25.4,5.9C40.3,65,39,69.5,39,74l16.8-9.3c2,0.2,4.1,0.3,6.2,0.3
c19,0,34.5-10.5,36.5-12.5S100.5,49.5,98.5,47.5z M85.5,50c-1.4,0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5s1.1-2.5,2.5-2.5s2.5,1.1,2.5,2.5
C88,48.9,86.9,50,85.5,50z" />
</symbol>
```