# Why the <use> element in SVG doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following simple example. It is stored in **image.svg**:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <g id="shape">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

However, putting this code in a HTML file doesn't load anything. Why is that?

```html
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#shape" x="10" y="10" />
</svg>
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Stack Snippets are isolated from each other (so that an id in one document doesn't conflict with an id in another document). In general this should be possible though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the use-tag inside the SVG with the shape you want to use:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <g id="shape">
            <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
        </g>
    </defs>

    <use xlink:href="#shape" x="10" y="10" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I think both SVGs in the same document also works: https://jsfiddle.net/t31vgbaj/

Comment: So if I put this code in image.svg and load it using <img src="image.svg">, should it work?

Comment: @lonesomeday Which means this answer is not only factually wrong, but also answers a different question.

Comment: @BarbuDorel no, images are self-contained and cannot have external references. Nor can they be references for other content.

Comment: Nowadays you should use href attribute instead of xlink:href. Read more on [mozilla.org - xlink:href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href)

Comment: Reference says that if no id is supplied, it should take the root element.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using elements from another document, you have to specify the document!

```
<use xlink:href="#shape" x="10" y="10" />
```

This means "use the `#shape` element from the current document".

To import from another document, you need to put the reference to the SVG file in the `xlink:href` attribute:

```
<use xlink:href="image.svg#shape" x="10" y="10" />
```

Obviously you need to check the path is correct here. Note that this is not supported in any version of Internet Explorer, though polyfills are available.

Answer (score 7):

For external svg files you need the namespace ... and I have added a fill to render the circle otherwise it will be transparent:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <symbol id="shape" width="200" height="200" viewbox="0 0 200 200">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="currentColor" />
  </symbol>
  <text y="20">Symbol above will not render unless referenced by use element</text>
</svg>
```

Then when you reference it you need to use the correct namespace for xlink:

```css
svg.defs-only {
  display:block; position: absolute; 
  height:0; width:0; margin: 0; padding: 0; 
  border: none; overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
  color: orange;
  stroke: red;
}

.purple {
  color: purple;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg class="defs-only" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <symbol id="shape" width="50" height="50" viewbox="0 0 50 50">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="currentColor" stroke="inherit" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <use xlink:href="#shape" x="10" y="10" />
   <use xlink:href="#shape" x="80" y="10" class="purple" />
</svg>
```

If you are referencing an external file, you need to put the filename before the `#` e.g. `image.svg#shape` making sure you get the path correct of course.

Note, not all browsers support fragment identifiers - notably IE and Edge - you need to use a javascript polyfill like svg4everybody for those browsers.

Workaround - use svg inline only

Comment: The `xmlns:xlink` bit was key for me when trying to do a `<use>` within the same file, but loading that file as an `<img>` in an HTML file. Without it, it wouldn't render.

Comment: Note - `xmlns:xlink` is now obsolete with svg 2.0 ... see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href for more details

Answer (score 0):

[SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#struct-UseElement) (when implemented in browsers) will allow to reference another SVG file without any [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment):

> New in SVG 2: An `href` without a fragment allows an entire SVG document to be referenced without having to ensure that it has an ID on its root element.

Before (SVG 1.1):

```xml
<!-- my-vector.svg -->

<svg id="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="10" cx="12" cy="12" />
</svg>
```

```xml
<use href="my-vector.svg#icon"></use>
```

After (there will be no need to define `id="..."` on the `svg`):

```xml
<!-- my-vector.svg -->

<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="10" cx="12" cy="12" />
</svg>
```

```xml
<use href="my-vector.svg"></use>
```

SVG 2 seems to be in the process of development in major browsers (see [this Chrome feature](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408) and specifically this Chromium issue: [Issue 366545: [SVG2] Allow  to reference entire files](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=366545)).