# How to refer to values set in the parent document in an element imported via <use>

Tags: svg

For a toy project I'm working with random flag designs and random flag colors.  Since the paths are a huge chunk of ugly exported SVG, I'd like to have all these shapes put into a library SVG.  That way, the generator would only have to create a small, simple-to-read stub to define the colors, and import the designs from the library.

A pair of demonstration files.

**flaglib.svg:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1 Tiny//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-tiny.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 500 300" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Design1">
    <rect width="500px" height="300px" fill="url(#BACKGROUND_PRIMARY)" />
    <circle cx="250px" cy="150px" r="90px" fill="url(#FOREGROUND_PRIMARY)" />
</g>

...

</svg>
```

**flagstub.svg:**

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1 Tiny//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-tiny.dtd">
<svg version="2.0" baseProfile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
     y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="BACKGROUND_PRIMARY"><stop offset="50%" stop-color="#F00" /></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="FOREGROUND_PRIMARY"><stop offset="50%" stop-color="#FF0" /></linearGradient>
</defs>
<use href="flaglib.svg#Design1"></use>
</svg>
```

The tag with the ID #BACKGROUND_PRIMARY is only defined once, so when it imports the missing text before it renders, it shouldn't be pulling a value for that from anywhere else.  And yet, they ignore the values set.

So:  how can the SVG elements imported from the library file use the colors defined in the stub fule?

Answer (score 0):

What browser(s) are you testing with? Last I checked, only Firefox properly supports external use references.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215009/how-to-reference-external-svg-file-in-svg-correctly) for more discussion on this topic.